# Why does the UTF-16 bytes for emoji smiley and emoji flag together looks different than a sequence of their individual UTF-16 bytes?

Tags: .net, string, character-encoding, utf-16, surrogate-pairs

Following is from the Visual Studio's C# Interactive Compiler:

```
> BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(""))
"D8-3D-DE-00"
> BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(""))
"D8-3C-DF-F4"
> BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(""))
"D8-3D-DE-00-D8-3C-DF-F4-DB-40-DC-67-DB-40-DC-62-DB-40-DC-65-DB-40-DC-6E-DB-40-DC-67-DB-40-DC-7F"
```

Emoji smiley's code units are a surrogate pair as expected - "D8-3D-DE-00"

Emoji flag's code units are a surrogate pair as expected - "D8-3C-DF-F4"

Given that, shouldn't the code units of emoji smiley followed by emoji flag have been - "D8-3D-DE-00-D8-3C-DF-F4"?

Answer (score 2):

The latter isn't a simple *black flag* emoji but a [Emoji Tag Sequence](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-tag-sequence/):

> Flag: England
>
> Emoji Meaning: The flag for England, a country in the United Kingdom.
> May show as the letters `gbeng`.
>
> The Flag: England emoji is a tag sequence combining  Black Flag, 
> Tag Latin Small Letter G,  Tag Latin Small Letter B,  Tag Latin
> Small Letter E,  Tag Latin Small Letter N,  Tag Latin Small Letter
> G and  Cancel Tag. These display as a single emoji on supported
> platforms.
>
> Flag: England was added to Emoji 5.0 in 2017.

I have written *PowerShell* cmdlet `Get-CharInfo` formerly and here's the result for your string (the column `CodePoint` contains Unicode (U+hhhh) and UTF-8 bytes, the column `Description` contains a surrogate pair if any):

```
 ""      | Get-CharInfo

Char CodePoint                      Category Description
---- ---------                      -------- -----------
   {U+1F600, 0xF0,0x9F,0x98,0x80} So       GRINNING FACE (0xd83d,0xde00)
   {U+1F3F4, 0xF0,0x9F,0x8F,0xB4} So       WAVING BLACK FLAG (0xd83c,0xdff4)
   {U+E0067, 0xF3,0xA0,0x81,0xA7} Cf       TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER G (0xdb40,0xdc67)
   {U+E0062, 0xF3,0xA0,0x81,0xA2} Cf       TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER B (0xdb40,0xdc62)
   {U+E0065, 0xF3,0xA0,0x81,0xA5} Cf       TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER E (0xdb40,0xdc65)
   {U+E006E, 0xF3,0xA0,0x81,0xAE} Cf       TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER N (0xdb40,0xdc6e)
   {U+E0067, 0xF3,0xA0,0x81,0xA7} Cf       TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER G (0xdb40,0xdc67)
   {U+E007F, 0xF3,0xA0,0x81,0xBF} Cf       CANCEL TAG (0xdb40,0xdc7f)
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight (and clarification). But, do you know, why my second command (`Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes("")`) didn't return all the bytes associated with Flag:England? I must add, I copy pasted Flag:England between the two commands.

Comment: There is actually "" _waving black flag_ only in your 2nd example in contradiction to the 3rd one where is  _Flag: England_… Do you mean _copy paste_ by keyboard and/or mouse or programmatically? @Sumith

Comment: Via clipboard. Ctl+C Ctl+V. @JosefZ.

Comment: But if I copy paste to overwrite the flag in second command, it continues to put out 2 code units (1 surrogate pair).
So it looks like when copy pasted along side a emoji smiley, waving black flag changes to Flag:England (GB is my locale).

Comment: @Sumith A weirdness in _Visual Studio_: copy&paste from your question  "", set cursor to the trailing (or leading) `"` and repeatedly tap keyboard's _left arrow_ (or _right arrow_) to navigate to the leading (or trailing) `"`. **How may taps** you need? Four in _Visual Studio Code_ but **16** (sixteen) in _Visual Studio_, ha-ha!!!